# Excel VBA - Using Error Traps where Another Routine is Called

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, call

I have a module with several routines where each routine is run by a Call statement. I am trying to put Error Traps in each routine, but the the Error Traps are triggered even if there is no error.

Example

```
public sub Macro1()

*some DIM statements*

On Error GoTo Errhandler

*some code
*
errhandler: MsgBox "Error! Contact developer"
Exit Sub


Call AnotherRoutine

End Sub
```

I have tried moving the errhandler statement below the Call statement in case this was to do with the order of the coding, but I still got the same problem

Comment: Move the `errhandler` below the `Call` statement, and move the `Exit Sub` before the `errhandler`.

Comment: In which case should `AnotherRoutine` run? At the moment, it will never run. Also, the `Call` keyword is considered deprecated and you can safely omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Macro1 is not valid syntax. I think you meant `End Sub` after the error handler. Error handling isn't like handling conditions with an If. The label is simply a place in the code to jump to when there is an error.

You can wrap the message box in an If to test for an error or you can add an `Exit Sub` just above the label.

```vb
Public Sub Macro1()
    On Error Goto ErrHandler
    ...
    If Err > 0 Then MsgBox MYMESSAGE
End Sub
```